# return AD DNS record of same site

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I have 2 site:
BEZA (datacenter)
BEOM (office)

In both sites, there are 2 domain controllers (with DNS installed). I have assigned the DC's to the specific site.

When I try to resolve the domain, I get random records, from 1 of the 4 dc's. So it could be that, when you try to authenticate against ldap on site BEZA, it actually uses a DC on BEOM.
Today we had an issue with our DC's in BEOM. All applications in BEZA could not authenticate anymore. If I do a couple of ipconfig /flushdns, I get the right (local) DC ip.
How can I 'force' that DNS returns a record of a DC in the same site as the application/user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe I did not explain it right, but it was more a DNS issue then an uactual AD issue.
I have software that does an LDAP request to my domain name (intra.mydomain.com). When I do a nslookup for intra.mydomain.com in BEOM, I would expect to get the DC of BEOM as a result. When I do a nslookup for intra.mydomain.com in BEZA, I would expect to get the DC of BEZA as a result. 
This was not working. But apparantly, that is because my subnet prioritization was not working well, and that was because it matches the wrong part of the ip. 10.101.**1**.1 instead 10.**101**.1.1. This can be fixed with this command:

```
Dnscmd /Config /LocalNetPriorityNetMask 0x0000FFFF
```

Now when I query intra.mydomain.com, I get a DC from the same location as a result.

Source: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2013/02/18/how-netmask-ordering-feature-in-dns-affects-the-resultant-queries/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you don't.  It is possible to not register DNS records for the office (BEOM), so that way applications in the data center always have only their local DNS records. And clients in the BEOM site will always use their DC's first because they use those DC's for DNS.  But if a domain controller is registered in DNS, those records will be returned in a query for the domain.  This approach is very common for hub-and-spoke topologies.

It's unlikely the issue is caused by a straight DNS lookup though, because the DC Locator process is far more sophisticated than just a DNS query.

How to optimize the location of a domain controller or global catalog that resides outside of a client's site
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306602

"DC locator DNS records not registered by the DCs" Net Logon service group policy.

Answer (score 0):

`When I try to resolve the domain, I get random records, from 1 of the 4 dc's. So it could be that, when you try to authenticate against ldap on site BEZA, it actually uses a DC on BEOM` - That's a bit of a red herring. Querying the domain name in DNS using something like nslookup or dig isn't the same as locating a domain controller against which to authenticate. Querying the domain name in DNS via nslookup or dig should return all Domain Controllers regardless of site. That's the normal and expected behavior. That DOES NOT mean that your clients or your applications are going to use a random DC to authenticate against.

Do you have your subnets created and associated with the appropriate site in Active Directory Sites and Services?

Domain Controllers will register site specific records in DNS when you have ADS&S configured correctly. When an AD client queries DNS for the location of a DC, a local DC will be returned based on the client subnet if those subnets have been defined in ADS&S. The client will then create "affinity" with that site so that subsequent logons use the DC's in that site. This applies to the Domain Controller locator process. How your applications behave may be a different matter altogether.